# javadoc: classpath for all jars in the project

Tags: java, javadoc

When generating documentation using javadoc, I have to provide classpath for external jars otherwise I get "unknown package or class" error. The problem is that I have over 30 jars and I have to list them all in the classpath using absolute path like so

```
javadoc -classpath C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\jar1\1.0\jar-name.jar:C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\jar2\1.0\jar-name.jar
```

Is there a way I can specify the path where all these jars can be found? or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: guessing from the .m2/repository paths you seem to be using maven already, have you considered the [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/)?

Comment: You should not be running `javadoc` directly. Almost no one does that. Let Maven invoke it for you.